Dell XPS Plus 9320 no webcams found in Ubuntu 22.04
Hello I am using Dell XPS Plus 9320 with Ubuntu 22.04. My built-in camera used to work and recently it stopped from working where it was always black both in web browsers and in Cheese but at least detected. I tried to solve the problem using the commands mentioned in the answers here
Dell XPS Plus 9320 webcam not detected in Ubuntu 22.04
However I made the things worse, now no web cameras are found in web browsers and in Cheese it shows : There was an error in playing the video from the webcam.
The output of  lsusb  is :
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:63bc Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8086:0b63 Intel Corp. USB Bridge
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

I would like to say that when I reboot my PC, it shows in red that it failed to start Kernel modules. I am not sure how to solve this problem, do you have any idea on how to go further ?
